# Normal form for a relation where the number of tuples having the same value in a column is the same for all the possible values in that column

Tags: normalization, relational-theory

Is there a normal form for a relation that would permit the following table :

```
id | alpha
----------
1  | a
1  | b
1  | c
2  | g
2  | u 
2  | k
.
.
.
n  | x
n  | y
n  | z
```

But not this table :

```
id | alpha
----------
1  | a
1  | b
2  | g
2  | u 
2  | k
.
.
.
n  | x
n  | y
```

Comment: Normal forms are about how **columns** in a table relate to each other (and to columns in other tables).  Normal forms don't address how **rows** relate to each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How would you populate such a relation? If you required 3 records per id the relation could not exist, as when it is first created this criteria will not be met (until the relation is populated with records).

I think this would have less to do with normal form and more to do with database constraints. Even then, I think it would only allow a MAX of n records with the same id, but not a minimum. Resulting in 0-n records per id.

What problem are you solving? Perhaps some fresh eyes could guide you toward a new approach.

Comment: In my application , I have to maintain a table with these two fields, where the id field is a foreign key that is autogenerated in some other table. Assuming that the data upload to the table is reliable and happens in a transaction, I have to make sure that for every id , a certain fixed number of records are stored in this table. However, this number is not known to me beforehand and is only available when I have inserted all the records for the first id in table. Thereafter , all the ids inserted must have the same number of records.

Comment: Ah, as long as the import is occurring in a single transaction, this might be a good use case for a trigger. The trigger would apply your business logic and check the rows that were just inserted and take appropriate action based on what it finds.